# AppleScript export PowerPoint slides as images

Tags: applescript, powerpoint

Following code is correct but nothing happens. Can you help please ?

```
tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"
    open "/Users/pierreduran/Documents/Pres/pres.pptx"
    activate
    set theOutputPath to ((path to desktop) as text) & "pnghole:"
    --display dialog theOutputPath
        
    tell active presentation
        try
            save in theOutputPath as save as PNG
        on error err
            display dialog "err: " & err
        end try
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: What is your *theOutputPath*? It should be something like `((path to desktop) as text) & "pnghole:"`. Note… do not use the desktop as your output path (don't use any existing folder as your output path) — at least in PPT2011, your desktop will be overwritten. Thanks microsoft.

Comment: By the way, you should format your code by putting three backticks (ie \```) in the line immediately above and below your code. Don't put anything else in those lines. Alternatively, you can select all of your code statements and click the `code sample` button in the editor (looks like `{}`)

Comment: hi thank you for answering. I have just updated my lines of code regarding your comment but nothing still happens: not extracting slides.

what am i doing wrong please ?

Comment: Remove the try statement and run it. What is the result?

Comment: no error and nothing happens. i have office LTSC 2021 and monterey 12.6.7.
Is is working from your side ? what are your conditions ?

Comment: It works fine for me. I am using PPT 2011 on sierra 10.12. Too fine actually… I deleted my desktop folder when I used it as the save location :)

Comment: ahah fancy, i would love that too ! so the issue is between MacOS and Office versions... sad.

Comment: I think that around 2016, apple made some changes and then microsoft incorporated them. The primary issue was around sandboxing the app and it affected the saving of files. You might try searching for something more generic, e.g. 'applescript powerpoint save file', or something like that. Another approach to look into would be using vba. Applescript can call vba but with some limitations. Just a couple of alternative ideas.